# WSDL server HTTP headers

Tags: http, http-headers, weblogic, websphere, wsdl

I am sending request to WSDL server, and I have some funny results. In about 9 of 10 cases I got error from server, however in 1 of 10 I got successful response.

Headers from successful response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2011 09:34:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
x-wily-servlet: Clear appServerIp=x.x.x.x&agentName=esb_online_server4&servletName=HttpTransportServlet&servletResponseTime=4&agentHost=z2esb04.xxx.com&agentProcess=WebLogic
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
x-wily-info: Clear guid=24573561C68E76520E3CD0AC3E3A7EC9
Content-Length: 568
Connection: close
```

From failure:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2011 09:34:45 GMT
Server: WebSphere Application Server/5.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Connection: close
Content-Length: 521
```

I am trying to figure our where is the problem, however I am responsible for client side only. Does it mean that there are two different servers that may respond to same request with same URL, and therefore it must be problem somewhere in backend configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure looks like there are multiple separate servers responding to that same URL, thus that same IP address. I suspect some kind of IP sprayer is being used and is distributing between a WebLogic server (which understands the URL) and a WebSphere one (which doesn't).

When you get the 200 response, do you also receive WSDL data content?

Comment: Yep. It seems there is a problem on the backend side - load balancer forwards requests to different servers, and one of them is misconfigured.